anchor lang bankrun test: CPI calls from my program to external program result in `Program is not deployed` log error
I am trying to refactor my test suite from the standard anchor lang test suite, to one that uses bankrun, and I am running into a really weird issue. The final test is having my program interact with an external hyperlane bridge program in order to bridge tokens from eclipse mainnet back to ethereum mainnet. In my original test suite this works fine, but in my bankrun refactored one I keep getting an error that the program is not deployed.
  'Program AWzzXzsLQvddsYdphCV6CTcr5ALXtg8AAtZXTqbUcVBF invoke [1]',
  'Program log: Instruction: TransferRemote',
  'Program log: Verifying signer: ADphsRxumkgpBtCzDvCrZTP7skvojiCeMSYdAomnbst6 against stored strategist: ADphsRxumkgpBtCzDvCrZTP7skvojiCeMSYdAomnbst6',
  'Program log: Verifying configuration matches stored hash',
  'Program log: Transferring tokens to strategist',
  'Program TokenzQdBNbLqP5VEhdkAS6EPFLC1PHnBqCXEpPxuEb invoke [2]',
  'Program log: Instruction: TransferChecked',
  'Program TokenzQdBNbLqP5VEhdkAS6EPFLC1PHnBqCXEpPxuEb consumed 8202 of 140597 compute units',
  'Program TokenzQdBNbLqP5VEhdkAS6EPFLC1PHnBqCXEpPxuEb success',
  'Program log: Creating and executing transfer remote instruction',
  'Program EqRSt9aUDMKYKhzd1DGMderr3KNp29VZH3x5P7LFTC8m invoke [2]',
  'Program is not deployed',
  'Program EqRSt9aUDMKYKhzd1DGMderr3KNp29VZH3x5P7LFTC8m failed: invalid account data for instruction',
  'Program AWzzXzsLQvddsYdphCV6CTcr5ALXtg8AAtZXTqbUcVBF consumed 73021 of 200000 compute units',
  'Program AWzzXzsLQvddsYdphCV6CTcr5ALXtg8AAtZXTqbUcVBF failed: invalid account data for instruction'

For reference my program id is AWzzXzsLQvddsYdphCV6CTcr5ALXtg8AAtZXTqbUcVBF, and the external program I am interacting with is EqRSt9aUDMKYKhzd1DGMderr3KNp29VZH3x5P7LFTC8m.
I am loading the external program in when I call startAnchor by including it in the allAccounts array. context = await startAnchor(PROJECT_DIRECTORY, [], allAccounts); here.
Weirdly enough when I add the external program executable data to the allAccounts array it caused half the tests to fail. I believe it is some timeout issue.
So to get around this I made a helper function that takes in an array of accounts, then it calls client.getAccount(account) to get the account info and see if it exists locally. If it does not then it calls connection.getAccountInfo(account) in order to grab the external account from the rpc, then calls context.setAccount(account, accountInfo). And even with doing this and confirming that the programs/accounts are all set locally I still get the above log error.
This is my PR where I am refactoring my test suite if you want to see the code. One other thing I noticed was that the token 2022 program and executable data seems to be automatically loaded into the test environment because I did not need to add it.
I should also mention that the reason why I am refactoring to use bankrun is I need the ability to write arbitrary account data so that I can give my test accounts real eclipse mainnet tokens, and properly test my programs integration with eclipse. My old test suite got around this by relying on the keypair on my computer which was used to derive very specific accounts which I could then manually transfer tokens to on eclipse.
So I guess my question boils down to "Am I doing something wrong when loading external programs into bankrun?". If anyone has a link to repo where they use anchor lang and bankrun in their test suite, and load in external accounts/programs that would be extremely helpful. Thank you! :)

I took a break and figured it out. I just needed to use solana program dump <PROGRAM ACCOUNT> <PROGRAM NAME> and output it to a file in ./tests/fixtures, then when calling anchor start, pass in the programs to deploy.
 context = await startAnchor(
  PROJECT_DIRECTORY,
  [
    {
      name: "hyperlane_router",
      programId: HYPERLANE_ROUTER_PROGRAM_ID,
    },
    {
      name: "hyperlane_mailbox",
      programId: HYPERLANE_MAILBOX_PROGRAM_ID,
    },
    {
      name: "hyperlane_igp",
      programId: HYPERLANE_IGP_PROGRAM_ID,
    }
  ],
  allAccounts
);

